# Emacs - specify a prefix argument for cider-jack-in

Tags: emacs, clojure

In the bottom of [`this this Github PR for clojure-emacs`](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/pull/544), bbatsov says :

> @Bill You can also invoke `cider-jack-in` with a prefix argument and
>   you'll get prompted for a few things (like the command used to
>   jack-in).

How do I invoke `cider-jack-in` with a prefix ? For now I do `M-x` `cider-jack-in`. I would like to specify a profile interactively.

Comment: After asking on slack, @jcsims said :  the prefix argument is `C-u`, so it would be `C-u C-c M-j` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In emacs, `C-u` is used to specify a prefix argument before any command. Different commands treat prefixes differently, but you can generally expect a more customized response.

`C-u M-x cider-jack-in`

Comment: N.B. - if you have changed the binding of `C-u` (perhaps to make it be undo?), you can use `M-0` (or any of the other Meta + number keybindings which provide a numeric prefix)

Comment: Thanks ! I'm using prelude, and C-u seems to repeat the command. I get an `helm` error when doing `C-u M-x` : Error: specifying a prefix arg before calling `Help-M-x`, but I understand this is specific to prelude.

Comment: what about using `M-0` or `M-1` etc. ? there are lots of commands in the category of "prefix", hopefully one is accessible...

Comment: Oh wait, prelude isn't breaking `C-u` - you are getting the prefix, it's breaking `M-x`, and preventing it from getting prefixes. I'd stop using prelude, that's an egregious breakage (there are lots of useful behaviors you can get from prefixes)

Comment: If you are really committed to prelude, the other option is writing an interactive function that calls `cider-jack-in` with a non-nil argument.